# Cannot create new application through web2py admin interface - Permission denied

Tags: apache, web2py, amazon-ami

I have deployed web2py and integrated it with apache on my redhat linux AMI according to the instructions given at

```
http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1423/deploy-web2py-on-fedoracentosred-hat
```

Everything is working fine. I can open welcome page on port 80 and 443. When I try to access admin interface over HTTP, request gets denied as expected. But when I try to access interface over HTTPS, it asks for password. When I enter the password which I set while installation it redirects me to error page with some ticket number. When I click on the link it asks for me to provide admin password again. So I tried to read the file from errors folder of web2py application. This file says

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: \'/web2py/applications/admin/private/hosts.deny\'\n'
```

I thought this might be related to permissions so I gave full access to hosts.deny file. It is still exhibiting the same behavior. Please help me out.

---

Above problem has been solved by deleting existing hosts.deny file. 
Now I am able to access admin interface. However when I try to create a new application it doesn't allow and shows error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/web2py/gluon/admin.py", line 163, in app_create
    os.mkdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/web2py/applications/adv01'
```

I have checked out permissions of applications directory in web2py and it has `drwxr-xr-x.` access to `apache` user which also is its owner. I changed the permissions of the directory to `drwxrwxrwx` but it made no difference. Why is it still denying access?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that this issue is related to SELinux. So I run the following command to set context of applications directory:

```
sudo chcon -R -v -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t applications
```

It is now showing similar error message for other file as given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/web2py/gluon/admin.py", line 175, in app_create
    w2p_unpack('welcome.w2p', path)
  File "/web2py/gluon/fileutils.py", line 322, in w2p_unpack
    tarfile = open(tarname, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/web2py/welcome.tar'
```

I tried same command for this file as well but found out that there is no such file present there. Why welcome.tar is missing? How would I get it? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design with web2py. You should be able to edit /applications/admin/models/access.py so that you can access over http.